# fill_between 'where' arg thinks parameters are different size (but they aren't)

Tags: python, matplotlib

given:

```
line1_xclip = [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0, 110.0, 120.0, 130.0]
line1_yclip = [10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0]
line2_yclip = [0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

when I run:

```
ax.fill_between(line1_xclip, line1_yclip, line2_yclip, where=(line1_yclip<line2_yclip), color='b', interpolate=True, alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(line1_xclip, line1_yclip, line2_yclip, where=(line1_yclip>line2_yclip), color='r', interpolate=True, alpha=0.5)
```

I get:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:142:
> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Since 3.2, the parameter *where* must
> have the same size as [0.0 10.0 20.0 30.0 40.0 50.0 60.0 70.0 80.0
> 90.0 100.0 110.0 120.0 130.0] in fill_betweenx(). This will become an error two minor releases later.

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:143:
> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Since 3.2, the parameter *where* must
> have the same size as [0.0 10.0 20.0 30.0 40.0 50.0 60.0 70.0 80.0
> 90.0 100.0 110.0 120.0 130.0] in fill_betweenx(). This will become an error two minor releases later.

Yet if I check the shape:

```
print("line1_xclip shape = %s" % np.shape(line1_xclip))
print("line1_yclip shape = %s" % np.shape(line1_yclip))
print("line2_yclip shape = %s" % np.shape(line2_yclip))
```

> line1_xclip shape = 14

> line1_yclip shape = 14

> line2_yclip shape = 14

everything seems fine.

The process runs, but produces:

[image: monocolor output plot]

The same code has produced desired results with other data, for example:
[image: reversing color scheme]

I'm running Python 3.7.3, Numpy 1.16.4, and Matplotlib 3.3.1 in Jupyter Lab on a Windows 7-64 machine.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the data type.

I was trying to pass lists to a kwarg that needed arrays.

SOLVED by:

```
line1_xclip = np.array([0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0, 110.0, 120.0, 130.0])
line1_yclip = np.array([10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0])
line2_yclip = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0])
```

[image: desired color scheme]

Comment: All four parameters (x to where) would accept lists. The problem has been that the comparison of lists yields a scalar boolean, while the comparison of the arrays yields a boolean array.